# How do I test if IOS device has telephone capabilities?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to offer phone support in my app at the press of a button for iPhone users, and display a phone number for iPad/iPod Touch users.  Rather than detecting what device the user has, is there a better way to query the hardware to see if it has telephony capabilities?  This would continue to work should iPad 3G one day open up for voice calls.

I am aware of how to limit an app to devices through the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key, but I'm not looking to restrict platform, just detect capabilities.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Check if application can open tel url:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+11111"]])
  // device has phone capabilities
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks to be exactly what I'm looking for (minor revision to [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+11111"]).  I have only tested on iPhone so far, but the simulator reports that it can't make calls whilst the real device claims that it can!  Many thanks to both respondents!