# How to disable phone Call button only for iPod touch by xcode coding?

Tags: iphone, phone-call, ipod-touch

In my application I am showing business card as detail of showroom. In that detail I have given phone call option to user.

From iPhone we can call to respective number by giving code as follows..

```
 NSString* call = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phone_number];
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[call  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But from iPod I think we can not give phone call to respective number.

Now I want to launch application for iPhone and iPod but if I set Required device capabilities as "telephony" then App will not work on iPod. If I do not mention Required device capabilities as telephony and submit app as it is, will it be OK for Apple review process?
This will lead to have Phone call button on iPod with no function.

My question is how to disable phone call button and change text programmatically if user will install app on iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your app will not be in violation of guidelines if it degrades gracefully. You only need to declare device capability requirements if your app completely refuses to run without it.

From [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) (emphasis mine):

> If your app requires the presence or absence of specific device capabilities **in order to run**, you must declare those requirements using the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in your app’s Info.plist file. At runtime, iOS cannot launch your app unless the declared capabilities are present on the device. Further, the App Store requires this information so that it can generate a list of requirements for user devices and prevent users from downloading apps that they cannot run

For determining if the app can respond to `tel://` urls, see [How do I test if IOS device has telephone capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736110/how-do-i-test-if-ios-device-has-telephone-capabilities)
You essentially use `canOpenURL` to determine if a phone call can be made.

Comment: I also have button for "save business card details in contact" button. Is it OK with iPOD as I dont have iPod device for testing plz suggest..

Comment: The [iPod Touch](http://www.apple.com/ipodtouch/built-in-apps/more-built-in-apps.html) does have a Contacts app. You may want to consider acquiring an iPod Touch (3rd gen) for testing, though - used ones are very inexpensive on ebay, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the device can open `tel:` URLs and hide the phone button if not.

```
BOOL canCall = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:123456789"]];
```